# Gamepad axis getting constant events

Tags: usb, udev, joystick

I recently purchased a "Playmax Thunder Pad" USB gamepad, presuming it would be plug-and-play with linux (as gamepads tend to be), and much to my delight I have found that everything works correctly... except the right hand analog stick.

I can move the analog stick and the movement events are registered in `jstest-gtk` as well as `evtest`, but the x-axis of the stick appears to be sending constant events that it is moving 1 or 2 points from the center. This makes it impossible to play any games as the view only moves for a second before the stick is detected as being centered again.

I have tried calibrating the thing with no success.

Here is an example `evtest` output:

```
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x3 vendor 0x79 product 0xa version 0x110
Input device name: "Generic   USB  Joystick  "
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
    Event code 288 (BTN_TRIGGER)
    Event code 289 (BTN_THUMB)
    Event code 290 (BTN_THUMB2)
    Event code 291 (BTN_TOP)
    Event code 292 (BTN_TOP2)
    Event code 293 (BTN_PINKIE)
    Event code 294 (BTN_BASE)
    Event code 295 (BTN_BASE2)
    Event code 296 (BTN_BASE3)
    Event code 297 (BTN_BASE4)
    Event code 298 (BTN_BASE5)
    Event code 299 (BTN_BASE6)
  Event type 3 (EV_ABS)
    Event code 0 (ABS_X)
      Value    128
      Min        0
      Max      255
      Flat      15
    Event code 1 (ABS_Y)
      Value    128
      Min        0
      Max      255
      Flat      15
    Event code 2 (ABS_Z)
      Value    129
      Min        0
      Max      255
      Flat      15
    Event code 5 (ABS_RZ)
      Value    128
      Min        0
      Max      255
      Flat      15
    Event code 16 (ABS_HAT0X)
      Value      0
      Min       -1
      Max        1
    Event code 17 (ABS_HAT0Y)
      Value      0
      Min       -1
      Max        1
  Event type 4 (EV_MSC)
    Event code 4 (MSC_SCAN)
Properties:
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
Event: time 1493717417.256734, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 2 (ABS_Z), value 128
Event: time 1493717417.256734, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1493717417.264830, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 2 (ABS_Z), value 129
Event: time 1493717417.264830, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1493717417.280830, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 2 (ABS_Z), value 128
Event: time 1493717417.280830, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1493717417.288769, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 2 (ABS_Z), value 129
Event: time 1493717417.288769, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1493717417.384837, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 2 (ABS_Z), value 130
Event: time 1493717417.384837, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

ad infinitum.

**P.S.**

This is a linux-only issue, I can use this gamepad in my *other* installed OS with no issues whatsoever.

Comment: Try increasing the deadzone for the axis or calibrating the controller. Many games have one or both options available.

Comment: @Mioriin I tried that in jstest-gtk to no avail. P.S. I don't think it's that simple.